# How can I convert this dataframe into a multiple time series object in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time-series

I'm trying to clean up some data (https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv) regarding the COVID19 Novel Coronavirus to do various types of analysis (ie. create a chart of countries with 100 cases over time, or track the death-rate over time per country). I used data which had the dates as columns and countries as rows. I transposed the Dataframe so that I got a column for each country and a single column of dates as shown below.

[image]

I have attempted to read this dataframe in as a time series object through the following code:

```
covid19ts = ts(covid19, frequency = 365, start = c(2020,22))
```

The result is the following. Instead of getting dates as my index column I get a number from 1 - 47 (the number of days recorded). This results in me being unable to create charts or do any meaningful analysis.

[image]

I have also tried the following code using the lubridate package with the same results:

```
covid19ts = ts(covid19, frequency = 365, start= decimal_date(as.Date("2020-01-22")))
```

How can I make my ts dates into the actual dates for charting and analysis?

Or is there a completely different approach I could be using which would be better for the analysis im trying to do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could keep the data as a dataframe and do useful plotting. Maybe get the data in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv', check.names = FALSE)
df1 <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -(1:4)) 
head(df1)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  `Province/State` `Country/Region`   Lat  Long name    value
#  <fct>            <fct>            <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int>
#1 Anhui            Mainland China    31.8  117. 1/22/20     1
#2 Anhui            Mainland China    31.8  117. 1/23/20     9
#3 Anhui            Mainland China    31.8  117. 1/24/20    15
#4 Anhui            Mainland China    31.8  117. 1/25/20    39
#5 Anhui            Mainland China    31.8  117. 1/26/20    60
#6 Anhui            Mainland China    31.8  117. 1/27/20    70
```

If you want to convert the data into time-series as shown in your post, you could do :

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
         group_by(`Country/Region`, name) %>%
         summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = `Country/Region`, values_from = value, 
         values_fill = list(value = 0))

ts_data <- xts::xts(df2[-1], as.Date(df2$name, "%m/%d/%y"))
```

---

An alternative solution suggested by @G. Grothendieck relying on `zoo` is

```
z <- read.zoo(df1[c(2, 5:6)], index = "name", split = "Country/Region", 
              format = "%m/%d/%Y", aggregate = sum)
```

`read.zoo` avoids all the explicit aggregating and reshaping by `tidyverse`. We can then use `autoplot` function to plot this `zoo` object.

Comment: Insead of the code from `df2 <- ...` onwards consider `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(xts); library(ggplot2); library(scales);
z <-  read.zoo(df1[c(2, 5:6)], index = "name", split = "Country/Region", 
    format = "%m/%d/%Y", aggregate = sum); 
autoplot.zoo(z[, colSums(z) > 10000], facet = NULL) + scale_y_log10()`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck wow...that looks cool. Although I don't completely understand what 's going on there. Add as a separate answer?

Comment: `read.zoo` reads a file or data frame creating a zoo object using the column named by `index=` for time.  It defaults to `Date` class and it uses `format=` to interpret the dates.  If `split` is specified then the input is assumed to be in long form and the column whose name is specified in `split=` identifies the columns in wide form.  It applies the function specified in `aggregate=`, here `sum`, to aggregate cells having the same column and date so that dates are unique.  `autoplot.zoo` plots a zoo object using ggplot2.  `facet=NULL` means don't use separate panels.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `ts` or `xts` objects, this is best suited to a `tsibble` format like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)

covid19 <- read_csv("time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -(1:4)) %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(name)) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  rename(
    "Region" = `Province/State`,
    "Country" = `Country/Region`
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(Region, Country), index = date)

# Plot by country
covid19 %>%
  filter(Country %in% c("China", "Italy", "Iran", "South Korea")) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  autoplot(value)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>